python asyncio: How to get two infinite (with while True) async functions running concurrently?
I need to have several functions running concurrently and infinitely. I plan to use asyncio for this, and, if possible, I want to avoid using event loop directly.
I tried this code:
import asyncio
import os


class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = os.listdir('data')
        self.last_file = ''
        self.history = []

    async def wait_new_file(self):
        await self._wait_new_file()

    def _wait_new_file(self):
        while True:
            checked_files = set(os.listdir('data'))
            if new_file := checked_files.difference(set(self.files)):
                print(f'{new_file = }')
                self.last_file = list(new_file)[0]
                self.files.append(list(new_file)[0])
                self.history.append(f'>>>{self.files[-1]}')
                print(f'{self.files = }')
            if deleted_file := set(self.files).difference(checked_files):
                print(f'{deleted_file = }')
                self.files.remove(list(deleted_file)[0])
                print(f'{self.files = }')
            if os.path.exists('stop'):
                print(self.history)
                return

    async def check_difference(self):
        await self._check_difference()

    def _check_difference(self):
        flip = True
        while True:
            if flip and os.path.exists('flip'):
                flip = False
                print('on')
            if not flip and not os.path.exists('flip'):
                flip = True
                print('off')
            if os.path.exists('stop'):
                return

    async def main(self):
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            task_check_difference = tg.create_task(self.check_difference())
            task_monitor_files = tg.create_task(self.wait_new_file())

program = Program()
asyncio.run(program.main())

But with this, task_monitor_files is not doing any job, please tell what is wrong there?

There are probably way better file watcher hooks in your file system where the OS will notify your program if any file changes, instead of constantly needing to read the entire directory again and again.

Methods _wait_new_file and _check_difference should be defined as async methods because they have return statements and what they are returning, i.e. None, is not a coroutine. You will get an exception when they do return: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Ur problem is the way ur using asyncio and await's
In _wait_new_file and _check_difference methods, ur using while True loops, which is blocking some code.
When you call await self._wait_new_file() or await self._check_difference(), the execution will be stuck in these loop's and never return.
To fix this, you should make those methods async by using asyncio.sleep() instead of busy-waiting.
Here's an better version of your code:
import asyncio
import os


class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = os.listdir('data')
        self.last_file = ''
        self.history = []

    async def wait_new_file(self):
        while True:
            ... # ur code
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second before checking again

    async def check_difference(self):
        flip = True
        while True:
            ... # ur code
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second before checking again

    async def main(self):
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            task_check_difference = tg.create_task(self.check_difference())
            task_monitor_files = tg.create_task(self.wait_new_file())

program = Program()
asyncio.run(program.main())

Hope this will help you.
